# Spring Boot With Submodules Or Without Them?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I'm just a beginner and wandering if I have a lot different modules from different layers (domain service, domain entities, model, controller, fasade...), should I group them and create modules sub-modules sub-sub-modues etc. My project currently looks like this, is there something bad in my approach? I just want to know what are disadvantages of that and how you would do differently? :)

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJvwb.png)

Or I should put them all in the root directory of the project, in this case they all would be scattered and mixed together (what if I have over 100 modules), I feel like this is a bad approach. Or I'm wrong? But if I would want to change a specific module, I would have to look just in one root pom.xml file, and change only there, not going inside sub-modules, sub-sub-modules and looking at their pom.xml and changing there.

Comment: Take a look at structure which I have maybe you will get an idea how yours should look like: https://github.com/nazaryan/ShipIt/tree/bootintegration2/src/main/java/com/nkwebapps/shipit Regarding your question "What if I have over 100 modules" I would say if there is a needing to have 100 modules than you should have, it is important to have logical separation of groups of classes. And one small advice make sure to fully understand "Single responsibility" design principle

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding role of modules.Splitting the project into multiple modules is useful for example in case of a library some consumers of the project need only a subset of the classes, or the developers of the library want to make a clear distinction between what is public API and what is private implementation. And with big projects it may make the code easier to keep in order, even if it the code could technically be all in the same module.

For your case having proper packaging will help a lot.

```
 For Example: 
 All entity classes inside com.example.entity package
 All service classes inside com.example.service package and so on
```

Comment: I do not agree with you. Separating modules means separation of concerns which should be represented also in Maven modules...the deployment is not a reason to make a module or not...